# Change Visual Order of Overlapping Factor Values in geom_sf in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

(Load libraries)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
```

Let's say we have two points at the same position (x,y) but with different values (z):

```
x<-c(1,1)
y<-c(1,1)
z<-c(0,1)
```

I know that geom_point will change the order of the displayed values (which is on top), based on the ordering of the dataset:

```
ggplot(data=points, aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point(aes(color=z),size=20)
ggplot(data=points%>%arrange(desc(z)), aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point(aes(color=z),size=20)
```

[order 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdgDm.png)
[order 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcMBL.png)

And this still works if "z" is a factor.

If I make the points into sf objects and plot them using geom_sf, it works if "z" is numeric.

```
ggplot(data=points%>%st_as_sf(x=.,coords=c("x","y"),crs=4326) )+geom_sf(aes(color=z),size=20)

ggplot(data=points%>%st_as_sf(x=.,coords=c("x","y"),crs=4326) %>%arrange(desc(z)))+geom_sf(aes(color=z),size=20)
```

[sf num order 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pKPu.png)
[sf num order 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd8JG.png)

However, using geom_sf with factor(z), nothing changes when I reorder the dataset.

```
ggplot(data=points%>%st_as_sf(x=.,coords=c("x","y"),crs=4326) %>%mutate(z=factor(z)))+geom_sf(aes(color=z),size=20)

ggplot(data=points%>%st_as_sf(x=.,coords=c("x","y"),crs=4326) %>%mutate(z=factor(z))%>%
arrange(desc(z)))+geom_sf(aes(color=z),size=20)
```

[sf factor order 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9zyo.png)
[sf factor order 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnlOI.png)

How can I force the reordering in the last example?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last example, you can force the re-ordering by re-arranging the order of z before setting z as a factor and attributing unique values of z as factor levels as follow:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

points%>%
  st_as_sf(x=.,coords=c("x","y"),crs=4326) %>%
  arrange(desc(z)) %>%
  mutate(z=factor(z, levels = unique(z))) %>% str()

Classes ‘sf’ and 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ z       : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","0": 1 2
 $ geometry:sfc_POINT of length 2; first list element:  'XY' num  1 1
 - attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry"
 - attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "z"
```

In the `str` output, you can see that now factor levels are well organized (1 before 0) And if we plot it, you get the expected plot:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
ggplot(data=points%>%
         st_as_sf(x=.,coords=c("x","y"),crs=4326) %>%
         arrange(desc(z)) %>%
         mutate(z=factor(z, levels = unique(z))))+
  geom_sf(aes(color=z),size=20)
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?